# Is it possible to containerize a .Net Framework Azure Function App to Windows container?

Tags: docker, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app base on .Net Framwork. 
I'm looking for a dockefile that can create an image for windows container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Azure functions runtime only support .net core from 2.x. The docker images for Azure functions are from versions 2.x only. https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base

Comment: Thanks @jayasurya_j. I wonder if there is a dockerfile sample for Azure Function running on windows at all?

Comment: can you try following the same steps as of Linux, dockerfile shouldn't change for windows. But be wary of filename paths